# How to send JSONP request using int-http:outbound-gateway in Spring Integration?

Tags: service, jsonp, spring-integration

I am trying to convert a request working as in below call to Spring Integration Async call

```
function sendToSomething(){
    var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date());
    var emailAddress = $("#prefferedemail").val();

    // Call to Send email address to something
        $.ajax(
            {
                global: false,
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://xyz.something.com/pub/rf?_ri_=X0Gzc2X"
                    + "& EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_=I&email_address_=" + emailAddress + "&SOURCE_CODE=CPK&EMAIL_PREF_CH_DT=" + formattedDate,
                dataType : "jsonp",
            }   
        );
    }
}
```

Key point is its supposed to use **http** and **jsonp**

I am trying to configure  something like below

```
<int:gateway id="asyncSomeIntService"
        service-interface="com.staples.eoe.integration.AsyncSomeService" default-request-channel="someRequestChannel" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://xyz.something.com/pub/rf?_ri_=X0Gzc2X "&amp;EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_=I&amp;email_address_={emailAddress}&amp;SOURCE_CODE=CPK&amp;EMAIL_PREF_CH_DT={formattedDate}"
     http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" request-factory="requestFactory" 
     request-channel="someRequestChannel"   reply-channel="someReplyChannel">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="emailAddress" expression="headers.emailAddress" />
    <int-http:uri-variable name="formattedDate" expression="headers.formattedDate" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <property name="connectTimeout" value="5000" />
        <property name="readTimeout" value="5000" />
</bean>
```

And the idea was to call from Server layer as below

```
Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload("something")
                    .setHeader("formattedDate", "15-01-27")
                    .setHeader("emailAddress", customer.getPreferredEmail())
                    .build();
```

The Request submits the URL fine,
However I get part of response are as below 
"It is likely that your input did not pass our validation process."

Is there a way to send **JSONP** request like in above ajax call using Spring Integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question though!

However if we go to the jQuery docs, we'll see this description for the `dataType : "jsonp"`:

> If jsonp is specified, $.ajax() will automatically append a query string parameter of (by default) callback=? to the URL. The jsonp and jsonpCallback properties of the settings passed to $.ajax() can be used to specify, respectively, the name of the query string parameter and the name of the JSONP callback function. The server should return valid JavaScript that passes the JSON response into the callback function. $.ajax() will execute the returned JavaScript, calling the JSONP callback function, before passing the JSON object contained in the response to the $.ajax() success handler.

So, since Spring Integration HTTP support isn't jQuery-based framework, we should go with standard JSONP rules and add that `callback=?` parameter to the `url`.

But... since we are in the Java I don't think that we will be able to execute a returned response as JavaScript. Although, do we need that since we can parse response body in the downstream using Java JSON abilities?